# Find orthonormal bases for the orthogonal subset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

Let S be the subset
$$\{\left(1,0,2\right),\left(3,2,1\right),\left(1,-2,7\right)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$$
Find orthonormal bases for $S^{\perp}$ and $S^{\perp\perp}$

I have begun by putting these vectors in a matrix and reducing them to row echelon form which gives
$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$$

So we see the maximimal linearly independent subset is $\{\left(1,0,2\right),\left(3,2,1\right)\}$ and thses vectors for a basis of span S. Where do I go from here?

Comment: use the dot product to determine a vector with lies in the orthogonal complement... or even more directly with the old good cross product... for twice the orthogonal complement, just think long enough

Answer (score 1):

Throught the Gram-Schmid pprocess (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) find an orthonormal basis of $S$ which will also be a basis for $S^{\perp\perp}$ (we  can show this by the projection theorem also for infinite dimension vector spaces)

Of course, $\dim S^{\perp}=1$ so take a vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^{3}-S $ and take $\hat{z}  $ its orthogonal projection on $S $

Then you have that $z-\hat{z} $ lives in $S^{\perp}$ and therefore is a basis